# Некорректно работает якорное меню внутри блока со скроллом

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

**UPD** Запускать примеры кода нужно в маленьком размере, на всю страницу не разворачивать. Проблема возникает именно тогда, когда не все пункты меню видны изначально, и до них нужно скроллить мышкой.

---

Есть код на jQuery, который анимирует плавный переход к якорям. Он корректно функционирует, когда скроллится вся страница, однако внутри блока со скроллом всё работает криво:

```js
$('.main-nav a').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let elementClick = $(this).attr('href');
  let destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
  $('main').animate({ scrollTop: destination }, 1000);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 16px;
}
header, footer {
  height: 20vh;
  border: 1px solid maroon;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
main {
  height: 60vh;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.main-nav a {
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.content {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  height: 100vh;
}
#one, #four, #seven {
  background-color: red;
}
#two, #five, #eight {
  background-color: green;
}
#three, #six, #nine {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>header</header>
<main>
  <div class="main-nav">
    <a href="#one">1. One</a>
    <a href="#two">2. Two</a>
    <a href="#three">3. Three</a>
    <a href="#four">4. Four</a>
    <a href="#five">5. Five</a>
    <a href="#six">6. Six</a>
    <a href="#seven">7. Seven</a>
    <a href="#eight">8. Eight</a>
    <a href="#nine">9. Nine</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="one">One</div>
  <div class="content" id="two">Two</div>
  <div class="content" id="three">Three</div>
  <div class="content" id="four">Four</div>
  <div class="content" id="five">Five</div>
  <div class="content" id="six">Six</div>
  <div class="content" id="seven">Seven</div>
  <div class="content" id="eight">Eight</div>
  <div class="content" id="nine">Nine</div>
</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Понятно, что проблема с переменной `destination`. Пробовал рассчитывать её как расстояние от верха родителя до нужного блока. И для первых пунктов меню работает корректно. Но если поскроллить к нижним пунктам, то опять всё ломается:

```js
$('.main-nav a').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let elementClick = $(this).attr('href');
  //let destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
  let destination = $(elementClick).offset().top - $(elementClick).parent().offset().top - $(elementClick).parent().scrollTop();
  $('main').animate({ scrollTop: destination }, 1000);
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  height: 100vh;
  font-size: 16px;
}
header, footer {
  height: 20vh;
  border: 1px solid maroon;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
main {
  height: 60vh;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 20px;
}
.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.main-nav a {
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.content {
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  height: 100vh;
}
#one, #four, #seven {
  background-color: red;
}
#two, #five, #eight {
  background-color: green;
}
#three, #six, #nine {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>header</header>
<main>
  <div class="main-nav">
    <a href="#one">1. One</a>
    <a href="#two">2. Two</a>
    <a href="#three">3. Three</a>
    <a href="#four">4. Four</a>
    <a href="#five">5. Five</a>
    <a href="#six">6. Six</a>
    <a href="#seven">7. Seven</a>
    <a href="#eight">8. Eight</a>
    <a href="#nine">9. Nine</a>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="one">One</div>
  <div class="content" id="two">Two</div>
  <div class="content" id="three">Three</div>
  <div class="content" id="four">Four</div>
  <div class="content" id="five">Five</div>
  <div class="content" id="six">Six</div>
  <div class="content" id="seven">Seven</div>
  <div class="content" id="eight">Eight</div>
  <div class="content" id="nine">Nine</div>
</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```

Очевидно, что в `destination` ещё надо как-то учитывать этот скролл к нижним пунктам. Но не могу понять, как это сделать. Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все что Вам нужно, при подсчете позиции куда должен просколлироваться `main` - это суммировать высоты всех блоков ДО того блока по которому кликнули. Например: если у вас кликнули по `#one` - вы учитываете только высоту блока `main-nav`, если по `#two` - то уже `main-nav` + `#one`, если кликнули по `#three` то `main-nav` + `#one` + `#two`. И тд. Набросал примерный корявенький код, подправите под свои нужны и свой стиль. :)

```js
$('.main-nav a').on('click',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  let elementClick = $(this).attr('href');
  let destination = $(elementClick).offset().top;
  //Минимальная высота на которую будет сдвигаться вниз `main`
  let mainNav = $('.main-nav').outerHeight()+50;
  let hrefs=['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven', 'eight', 'nine'];
  let i, j, scrollH;
  scrollH = mainNav;
  //В зависимости от того по какой ссылке кликнули суммируем высоты предыдущих блоков
  for (i = 0; i < hrefs.length; i++ ) {
      if ( '#'+hrefs[i] === elementClick ) {
        for ( j = 0; j < i; j++ ) {
          scrollH = scrollH + $('#'+hrefs[j]).outerHeight();
        }
      }
  }
  //Плавненько скроллим :)
  $('main').animate({ scrollTop: scrollH }, 1000);
});
```

Я только не понял откуда у вас набегает 50px разницы между `main-nav` и `#two` - но верстка Ваша, думаю разберетесь :)

P.S Что-то мне подсказывают, что заминусуют опять...

Comment: я бы только hrefs с Вашего позволения в цикле формировал, а не так вот декларативно :) но в целом рабочий вариант, спасибо!

Comment: это дело вкуса :) ну никто не мешает сделать `for (i = 0; i < $('.main-nav a').length; i++ )` :)